# Sync 2 foundation orbit sliders

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, touchscreen, orbit

I'm attempting to use foundations orbit slider to create 2 sliders, one on top of the other.

I want these sliders to work together so that when 1 slides to slide1 the other does too. I have been able to achieve this on the most part by initiating a .click of one when another is clicked.

```
$('#sliderNav1a').click(function(){
    $('#sliderNav2a')[0].click();
});
```

However when I view it on a tablet the touch screen swipes don't sync.

Can anyone give me more information on how the swipe on a touch screen is initiated so that I can sync the two sliders together.

Comment: Have you looked at [jQuery Mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with different slider plugins, I found `slick.js` to be the best to achieve the synced slider that I am after.

[See codepen for example](http://codepen.io/garyvoss/pen/reaajR)